# What's "referenced_table_name" in CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating a deferred constraint trigger to make sure a parent has at least one child. There's this optional parameter `referenced_table_name` in the trigger definition, but its description gives no clue of its use.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createtrigger.html

> referenced_table_name
>
> The (possibly schema-qualified) name of another table referenced by
>   the constraint. This option is used for foreign-key constraints and is
>   not recommended for general use. This can only be specified for
>   constraint triggers.

I don't see how its presence affects the behavior of a trigger:

```
create table aaa_parent ( id int );
create table aaa_child ( parent_id int );


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ck_aaa_child__no_empty()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'trigger';
    if (TG_OP = 'DELETE' or old.parent_id != new.parent_id or (old.parent_id is not null and new.parent_id is null) ) then
        RAISE NOTICE 'differs';
        if exists(
            select * from aaa_parent where id = old.parent_id and not exists ( select * from aaa_child where aaa_child.parent_id = aaa_parent.id )
        ) then
            RAISE exception 'need at least one child for aaa_parent: %', old.parent_id;
        end if;
    end if;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SET search_path FROM CURRENT;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ck_aaa_child__no_empty on aaa_child;


CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER ck_aaa_child__no_empty
        AFTER update OR delete
        ON aaa_child
        -- FROM aaa_parent
        INITIALLY DEFERRED
        FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE ck_aaa_child__no_empty ()
;


delete from aaa_parent;
delete from aaa_child;

insert into aaa_parent values (9);
insert into aaa_child values (9);
update aaa_child set parent_id = 8;
```

Comment: A guess: maybe it prevents you from dropping the parent table while a constraint in the child table still references it. Without a `referenced_table_name` declaration in the trigger, PostgreSQL would have no realistic way of knowing that your trigger function expects the parent table to exist. The note on the documentation about foreign keys may imply that `referenced_table_name` exposes the same underlying mechanism that foreign-key constraints use to prevent the referenced table from being dropped.